# Contraction Action is Equivariant with Respect to Action of General Linear Group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, representation-theory

Let $k$ be of arbitrary characteristic, $R = k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ with $\deg(x_i) =1$.  Let $R_j$ be the $k$-space of monomials of degree $j$ with $k$-dual $D_j$, so that $R = \bigoplus_{j\geq 0} R_j$ and the graded $k$-dual of $R$ is given by $\bigoplus_{j\geq 0} D_j$.  We define an action of $GL_n(k)$ on $R_1$ as follows:

$$Ax_i = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ji}x_j = A^T\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{e}_i$$

Where $\textbf{x}$ is the column vector consisting of the variables.  Since $R_j = \operatorname{Sym}^j(R_1)$, it is not hard to see how to extend this to an action on $R$ such that $A(fg) = (Af)(Ag)$ for $f, g\in R$.

Now, for $\varphi\in D_j$, the action of $GL_n(k)$ on $D_j$ should be such that $A\varphi\in D_j$ is the functional

$$(A\varphi)(f) = \varphi((A^{-1})^Tf)$$

Now for $f\in R_i$ and $\varphi\in D_j$, we define $f\circ\varphi$ to be zero if $j < i$ and to be the functional on $R_{j-i}$ such that

$$g\mapsto \varphi(fg)$$

if $j\geq i$.  The claim, which I am unsure of, is that for $f, \varphi$ above, one has

$$A(f\circ \varphi) = Af\circ A\varphi$$

Of course this is trivial if $j < i$ (since the action of $GL_n(k)$ does not change the degree).  So for $j\geq i$, one has for $g\in R_{j-i}$

$$A(f\circ\varphi)(g) = \varphi((A^{-1})^Tg\cdot f)$$

$$(Af\circ A\varphi)(g) = A\varphi(Af\cdot g) = \varphi((A^{-1})^T(Af\cdot g))$$

And $(A^{-1})^T(Af\cdot g) = (A^{-1})^TAf\cdot (A^{-1})^Tg$.

So, something seems to have gone awry with our setup.

Edit:  I should mention a couple things.  This is nearly verbatim from Appendix A of the text *Power Sums, Gorenstein Algebras, and Determinental Loci*.  In the above construction, if we allow $GL_n(k)$ to act on $D$ as $A\varphi(g) = \varphi(A^{-1}g)$, then clearly we obtain equivariance.  However, this is not a group action on $D$.